# Identificar sesiones que realmente se encuentran vigentes en Oracle 12cR2

Tags: session, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-19c

Estoy trabajando con Oracle database 12cR2, y he identificado que en ciertas ocasiones cierro mi aplicación pero sin embargo en la tabla de V$Session continúan apareciendo las sesiones creadas por mi aplicación con un estado de INACTIVE, quisiera saber de una manera de realmente identificar que una sesión se encuentre vigente, espero que puedan apoyarme